# wamp server icon stays orange no skype, had uninstalled & reinstalled

Tags: php, wamp

I had an earlier version of wamp which I had uninstalled from control panel & deleted its folder in C drive. Than I tried to install it again.
But than the icon stays orange.
I checked the services, Apache is running but SQL was not. I started the SQL Services but even than it does not become green.
I have uninstalled the skype, changed the port as mentioned in other post but it is not working.
Php logs are showing an error. I am not able to figure out how to do it.
Please help.

Thank you.

Regards,
Meera

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer did you install?

Comment: The port change (80 to something else) is for Apache and if your apache is starting you do not need to change port 80

Comment: When you say you started SQLServices do you mean the service called `wampmysqld` or something else?

Comment: Have you looked at the MYSQL Error log?

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows Event Viewer for errors from MYSQL?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: If you installed a different and newer version of WAMPServer did you check you have all the MSVC RUntime Libraries installed [See Point 20 on the WAMPServer Troubleshooting Guide](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)

Comment: I installed wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b.

Comment: What about the answers to all the other questions

Comment: Apache is running. To start SQL services i clicked on wamp icon on system tray, & started services from there. But I just observed that it is getting shutdown immediately.  The log says: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2016-06-08 15:09:51 3072 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-08 15:09:51 3072 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Well "Do you have another MYSQL Server running"???

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Run the services snapin `Windows  Key+R` Enter `services.msc` and look to see if there is a service called `MYSQL`, wampservers mysql is called `wampmysqld`

Comment: Did you by any chance install something else that includes a MYSQL server, `MYSQL Workbench` or `XAMPP` maybe?

Comment: yes, my new project requires wordpress, so i am uninstalling that server and checking the wamp. will update you in some time. thank you so much for the help

Comment: yes, both the services are there in windows services snapin

Comment: You mean there is a `MYSQL` service as well as a `wampmysqld` service. In that case you should consider uninstalling that other MYSQL. **after backing up any databases you may have in the other MYSQL**

Comment: yes. I had both the services, I had installed MYSQL for earlier project. I took the back up & uninstalled & now my WAMP is green. Thank you so much for your advice. I could really figure it out.